# Cannot connect to database on Docker

Tags: postgresql, docker

I have created database on docker:
`docker run --name database -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password -d -p 5436:5436 postgres`
Created some database inside:

```
createdb database
```

Also created superuser. Now I am trying to connect from localhost:

```
psql -h localhost -p 5436 -U postgres
```

After that I get following error:

```
 psql: The server closed the connection unexpectedly
        This probably means that the server has terminated abnormally
        before or while processing your inquiry.
```

Ports are connected:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case, you are trying to expose `5436` and map with your host port `5436`, but that might need to use `-p 5436:5432` because Postgres uses port 5432 as the default port.

```
docker run --name database -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password -d -p 5436:5432 postgres
```

There is some description from [Container networking](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/)

> -p 8080:80：Map TCP port 80 in the container to port 8080 on the Docker host.